# Python requests.request with Post method download a zip file with incorrect content

Tags: python, python-requests, download, zip

I am sending the following request from the postman and with the option of 'Send and Download' I am downloading a zip file in response successfully. Following is Postman generated Python requests code and I'm not able to successfully download and save file programmatically:

```
url = 'https://myapi.url/goes-here'

payload = {
           'api_key': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
           'mode': 'low',
           'output': ['Excel',['Text']}
files = [
    ('file', ('myfile.xlsx', open(
        '/Users/myuser/Documents/project/myfile.xlsx',
        'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
]

headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

with open('my-file.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Downloaded file with above code has not correct content. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're most likely going to need to run a debugger on this code and see what the contents of the returned `response.content` is, because you haven't given us your API and the way they return data varies highly.

Comment: What does the raw response look like ?

Comment: RAW - RESPONSE 

<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f95a07d4588>

Comment: first check what you downloaded - or what you get in `response.content` - maybe it is HTML with some message which can explain what is the problem.